# NetSuite Summary Saved Search Can't Access Certain Fields

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to execute a saved search for work orders that evaluates a formula for each line item to determine whether the work order is ready to complete. I'm fairly confident that I know how my formula should work, but I don't seem to be able to access all the fields I need in my Formula (numeric). The fields I need are labeled "Quantity", "Backordered", "Committed", and "Used In Build. According to [this page](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/workorder.html), the IDs of these fields are `quantity`, `quantitybackordered`, `quantitycommitted`, and `quantityfulfilled`. I'm able to use the `quantity` and `quantitycommitted` without issues, but the other two just give me "ERROR: Field Not Found".

I've used two simplified searches to reproduce this. Under Results I have
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9aKa.png),
with "Sum" as the summary type and `{quantity}`
as the formula. This works as expected ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxGBZ.png)).
But when I change the formula to `{quantityfulfilled}` (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3W0m.png)) I get the error shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McnZt.png).

I'm very new to NetSuite; what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation page you linked is for the Work Order *record* - there is a different page for [Transaction *Search* IDs](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_1/script/record/transaction.html).

There you will see that to get quantities used on a build, you can reference Quantity Fulfilled/Received (`quantityshiprecv`).  AFAIK, backordered quantity is not directly available - but you can get it by using a formula `{quantity} - {quantityshiprecv} - {quantitycommitted}`.

Comment: Wow! It would never have occurred to me that those IDs would be distinct. Thank you!

Comment: The formula for backorders is helpful. I've looked for documentation on how this and other fields are calculated and haven't found anything. Is there a way (other than intuition) to find formulas for fields that aren't directly available in a search?

Comment: You can search for them in SuiteAnswers (YMMV), but if not found there you sometimes have to just reverse engineer the answer.  Often you will find something in SuiteAnswers that is not quite what you're looking for, but gives a clue that puts you on the right track.